# Can I upgrade Lenovo IdeaCentre K430 to AMD graphics?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have a Lenovo IdeaCentre K430 with an NVidia Geforce Gt620 graphics card. I would like to upgrade to an AMD Radeon HD 7750 but don't know if this is possible. If I got the GT620 model, am I limited to Nvidia cards? Or, can I still upgrade to an AMD card? In particular, the card requires CrossFireX, as I want to have two of them. Thanks for any help.

Comment: SLI or crossfire only come in to play if you plan to have 2 video cards in your system.  You can have a AMD or NVIDIA card in any system.

Comment: I do plan to have two cards eventually.

Comment: Nitpicking mode: Two **or more** video cards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a desktop with a PCI Express x16 port, put whatever you want in there, well, within the limits of your power supply that is. Since the 7750 requires no dedicated 12V, you should be fine. As far as a second card goes, I think that motherboard only has ONE PCI Express x16 slot, so don't get your hopes up.

Comment: They need to be x16 for graphics cards.

Comment: Would I be able to have two AMD cards?

Comment: Yes you can do that as long as you have 2 pcie x16 slots.

Comment: now, bear in mind it's only got a 280 watt powersupply, so any videocard that requires a dedicated powerline is going to be out of the question.

Comment: Just for the record: Graphics card do NOT need x16 slots. They work just fine (but slower) in open ended x1, x4 and x8 slots.

Answer (score 4):

You can put in just about any graphics card you want.  You are limited only by space.  The design of some motherboards and cases can cause issues with larger/longer add-in cards (like graphics cards).  The only other limitation is power.  It would appear your K430 uses a standard ATX power supply, so even if it doesnt supply enough power, it can be easily replaced.

Comment: Will two AMD cards still work?

Comment: Yes, it has 2 PCI express X 16 adapter slots.  However, it doesnt say what the power supply puts out.  You may have to replace it if you plan on running 2 high power GPUs.  Again, this is an easy/cheap to replace.